# Jira Automation: Ticket Field Inheritance

Tags: jira, jira-automation

I have a custom field titled `VCP Initiative` that goes across all tickets. I want to create an automation that if I create a Story that has a Parent Epic I want the `VCP Initiative` field to be copied over.

Example:

1. Epic created (EX-123) with the `VCP Initiative` field filled in as `Top5`
2. Create a story (ST-12)
3. Fill in `Parent Link` with EX-123
4. ST-12 is created and the `VCP Initiative` field auto-populates with `Top5`

Still trying to get use to the Automation area in Project Settings so help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an automation with the configuration below :

1- Trigger : **Issue created**

2- Condition : **Related issues condition**

- Related issues : **Epic**
- Condition : **Exists**

3- Action : **Edit issue**

- Choose field : **VCP Initiative**
- Set value : **Copy from parent**

Comment: Just tested it and it works perfectly, thank you!